# php: print multiple dynamic pages in A4 format

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, printing

I have some records in a database and I need, for each of them, to print a page in A4 format.

This is a sample of the page that needs to be printed https://i.stack.imgur.com/6i0XY.jpg

The text in red is dynamic, so for each record I will compile this letter and I have to print it. The average number is 450 pages, so this means 450 prints. Is this possible with php and javascript only ?

So far the only help I found is the `window.print()`, but how can I run this function for each record from the database and how to format the page as A4 ?

I don't know if it is even possible, the only things I found are about single pages.

Thank you

Comment: Probably the best thing to do is generate a PDF of your 450 page document. I've been using the php [MPDF library](http://www.mpdf1.com/mpdf/index.php) to generate print-ready output for a project I'm working on.

Comment: @cpilko The pdf is also a good idea, but how do you recommend handling all pages ? Do I create a single pdf file with all the pages, or individuals ?

Comment: It depends on your workflow for generating the output and what you do with it afterwards. If it's a batch type operation, I'd generate one big PDF so I've only got one file to print.